# Getting "Invalid Parameter - -fuzz" on ImageMagick convert command on Windows 10

Tags: windows, imagemagick

Getting this on the latest version of Windows (via GitHub Actions):

```
Command failed: convert.exe "D:\a\stone\stone\build\image.jpg" -fuzz 20% -fill ""#111111"" opaque ""#cc9aff"" "D:\a\stone\stone\build\image.new.jpg"
Invalid Parameter - -fuzz
```

What is the deal? I tried using `convert` instead of `convert.exe` but it was the same problem. I installed ImageMagick with `choco install imagemagick`. The end of the logs looks like this:

```
Download of ImageMagick-7.0.10-19-Q16-x64-dll.exe (32.51 MB) completed.
Hashes match.
Installing imagemagick.app...
imagemagick.app has been installed.
  imagemagick.app can be automatically uninstalled.
Environment Vars (like PATH) have changed. Close/reopen your shell to
 see the changes (or in powershell/cmd.exe just type `refreshenv`).
 The install of imagemagick.app was successful.
  Software installed to 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q16\'

imagemagick v7.0.10.19 [Approved]
imagemagick package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
 The install of imagemagick was successful.
  Software install location not explicitly set, could be in package or
  default install location if installer.

Chocolatey installed 3/3 packages. 
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
```

Any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has an existing convert.exe program to convert a FAT volume to NTFS. It appears this is being found earlier in your %PATH than the ImageMagick convert.exe.

You can verify this by running convert without any parameters. If you get a message 'Must specify a file system' then you are not running the ImageMagick executable.

If this is indeed the case, you can get around this by specifying the full location of the executable you want to run. I am guessing but it is probably:

```
C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q16\bin\convert.exe [parameters...]
```

You could add the ImageMagick bin directory to your %PATH but you would need to place it earlier than the main Windows directories for it to run before the 'standard' convert.exe but be aware that any other binaries in the IM folder would also take precedence. Another option is to add the IM directory to the end of your %PATH (it may be there already) and rename the IM convert.exe to something unique.

Comment: How can I know where the executable is _programmatically_? We only know it's that because we visually looked at the logs. But I am running this in the GitHub Cloud and I don't know what version it will be or where it will install. What do you recommend? Thanks for the answer, makes perfect sense.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Chocolatey but I see in the logs that it says `Software install location not explicitly set` so maybe you have the option of specifying location as part of the install. Alternatively, did Chocolatey update/append your @PATH as part of the install? You could inspect that programatically.

Comment: LAME! https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-install-directory-override

Comment: Hmmm, I see. Hopefully the free version appended the IM directory to your path and you can inspect it programatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `magick convert` instead of `convert`.